# How to increase the client side timeout on Firefox when 499 timeout occur?

Tags: php, nginx, firefox, timeout

I have a weird problem with Firefox, nginx and php. It seems like my Firefox times out after 10 seconds. I can see 499 status code from nginx in the console.

I have a simple web app with docker-compose, nginx and php. It is a simple php script that waits for 15 seconds until it returns some text. Firefox times out. Chrome and curl do not time out.

I have added to `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 mywebsite.localhost
```

If I visit http://mywebsite.localhost:8080/ with Firefox it will not load.

The php script in `src/index.php` looks like this:

```
<?php 

function info_log($message) {
  $out = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
  fputs($out, "$message\n");
  fclose($out);
}

$seconds = 15;
info_log("Before sleep $seconds seconds");
info_log("Request:\n");

foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
  info_log("$name => $value");
}

info_log("\n");

sleep($seconds);
info_log("After sleep $seconds");

echo "Hello after $seconds seconds of sleep! date: " . date('c') . "\n";

?>
```

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  php_backend:
    image: php:7-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app
  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
      - ./src:/app
```

The `./docker/nginx/site.conf` looks like this:

```
server {
    index index.php;
    server_name mywebsite.localhost;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /app;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php_backend:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

I start the app with:

```
docker-compose up
```

It works fine with curl:

```
curl http://mywebsite.localhost:8080/
Hello after 15 seconds of sleep! date: 2024-03-06T15:55:04+00:00
```

The logs for docker-compose looks like this with a curl call:

```
php_backend_1  | Before sleep 15 seconds
php_backend_1  | Request:
php_backend_1  | Accept => */*
php_backend_1  | User-Agent => curl/7.68.0
php_backend_1  | Host => mywebsite.localhost:8080
php_backend_1  | Content-Length => 
php_backend_1  | Content-Type => 
php_backend_1  | After sleep 15
php_backend_1  | 172.25.0.3 -  06/Mar/2024:15:55:38 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
nginx_1        | 172.25.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2024:15:55:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 76 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
```

It also works nicely with Chromium:

```
php_backend_1  | Before sleep 15 seconds
php_backend_1  | Request:
php_backend_1  | Accept-Language => en-US,en;q=0.9,sv;q=0.8
php_backend_1  | Accept-Encoding => gzip, deflate, br
php_backend_1  | Sec-Fetch-Dest => document
php_backend_1  | Sec-Fetch-User => ?1
php_backend_1  | Sec-Fetch-Mode => navigate
php_backend_1  | Sec-Fetch-Site => none
php_backend_1  | Accept => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
php_backend_1  | User-Agent => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
php_backend_1  | Upgrade-Insecure-Requests => 1
php_backend_1  | Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform => "Linux"
php_backend_1  | Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile => ?0
php_backend_1  | Sec-Ch-Ua => "Not(A:Brand";v="24", "Chromium";v="122"
php_backend_1  | Connection => keep-alive
php_backend_1  | Host => mywebsite.localhost:8080
php_backend_1  | Content-Length => 
php_backend_1  | Content-Type => 
php_backend_1  | After sleep 15
php_backend_1  | 172.25.0.3 -  06/Mar/2024:15:56:24 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
nginx_1        | 172.25.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2024:15:56:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 76 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

But with Firefox the page does not load and the docker compose logs looks like this:

```
php_backend_1  | Before sleep 15 seconds
php_backend_1  | Request:
php_backend_1  | Sec-Gpc => 1
php_backend_1  | Sec-Fetch-User => ?1
php_backend_1  | Sec-Fetch-Site => none
php_backend_1  | Sec-Fetch-Mode => navigate
php_backend_1  | Sec-Fetch-Dest => document
php_backend_1  | Upgrade-Insecure-Requests => 1
php_backend_1  | Connection => keep-alive
php_backend_1  | Dnt => 1
php_backend_1  | Accept-Encoding => gzip, deflate, br
php_backend_1  | Accept-Language => en-US,en;q=0.5
php_backend_1  | Accept => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
php_backend_1  | User-Agent => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:122.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/122.0
php_backend_1  | Host => mywebsite.localhost:8080
php_backend_1  | Content-Length => 
php_backend_1  | Content-Type => 
nginx_1        | 172.25.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2024:15:57:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:122.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/122.0"
php_backend_1  | After sleep 15
php_backend_1  | 172.25.0.3 -  06/Mar/2024:15:57:27 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
```

I expected Firefox to work as well but it didn't. I can get 499 status code in the logs. I am quite  confident that it is Firefox that aborts the connection. I could replicate the same behaviour if I kill the curl command just after I have started it.

I have searched for how to config Firefox. I have found that I can go to `about:config` in Firefox and change `network.http.connection-timeout`. But I have tried a lot of different values (0, 60, 60000) but that does nothing.

Do you have any ideas on what I can do?